# Reading JSON string in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

When i try to read a JSON string like below it goes to endless loop.

```
<script language="javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {

               $("#Button1").click(function() {
                   var json = "[{'City':'Lucknow','ID':'1'},{'City':'Mumbai','ID':'2'}]";
                   $.each(json, function() {
                       alert(this['City']);
                  });


           });
    </script>
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong? Please helpme out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the JSON string with jQuery:

```
var json = "[{'City':'Lucknow','ID':'1'},{'City':'Mumbai','ID':'2'}]";
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(json), function() {
    alert(this['City']);
});
```

The advantage of `jQuery.parseJSON` is that it uses the native implementation `JSON.parse` of the browser if it supports it.

---

**Edit**    The problem that this is not working is probably that JSON does only allow strings to be declared with double quotes. The corresponding [excerpt from the JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5):

> ```
>      string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
>
>      char = unescaped /
>             escape (
>                 %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
>                 %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
>                 %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
>                 %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
>                 %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
>                 %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
>                 %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
>                 %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
>                 %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
>
>      escape = %x5C              ; \
>
>      quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
>
>      unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
> ```

So the following should work:

```
var json = '[{"City":"Lucknow","ID":"1"},{"City":"Mumbai","ID":"2"}]';
```

Comment: @Bala: Oh, `jQuery.parseJSON` was added in 1.4.1. Maybe your jQuery version does not support it.

Comment: @Bala: Then it is supposed to be available. Try is also with the shortcut of `jQuery`: `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: @Bala: Now I know where the problem is: JSON only allows double quotes for strings. So `jQuery.parseJSON('[{"City":"Lucknow","ID":"1"},{"City":"Mumbai","ID":"2"}]')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
  var json = $.parseJSON("[{'City':'Lucknow','ID':'1'},{'City':'Mumbai','ID':'2'}]");
  $.each(json, function() {
    alert(this['City']);
});
```

It's better to use json2.js from: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: var json = "[{'City':'Lucknow','ID':'1'},{'City':'Mumbai','ID':'2'}]";
                                  $.each(eval(json), function() {
                                     alert(this['City']);
                                  });


-- Only this works.

The above code with pasrJSON does not work. I am using jquery 1.4.1