# String Indexed Json jquery

Tags: jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading JSON string in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524489/reading-json-string-in-jquery)

The following Json String

```
{
   "direct":{
      "newvisits":3,
      "uniquevisits":3,
      "retvisits":0
   },
   "user":{
      "newvisits":4,
      "uniquevisits":4,
      "retvisits":0
   }
}
```

The elements `"direct"` and `"user"` etc. are **dynamically** filled values.

How can I access the values of `"direct"` and `"user"` using jquery? 
In detail Want to fetch the name of "direct" and "user"[dyanamically filled fields] and then the values under each category

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524489/reading-json-string-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005606/jquery-json-parsing

Comment: Take a look at [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)...  You'll have to convert that string into a JSON object before you can access the properties.  Is this data coming from an AJAX call perhaps?

Comment: Ya..me encoded a string indexed multi dimensional array and encode json using php and return the value to jquery

Answer (score 1):

Assuming retVal is the the JSON object.

`retVal.direct` or `retVal["direct"]` will give you direct object.

**EDIT**
For getting the keys you can do.

```
for(key in retVal){
   retVal['key'] // something like this.
}
```

Comment: I am sorry..actuall i doesnot mean how to fetch the value of direct or user,First I wanna fetch the name "direct",then the values in side direct

Comment: "direct" would be in `key` there and its values in `retVal['key']`